# How to convert an array of data into an array of Leaflet LatLngs?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I GET all the locations (latitude + longitude) that works good I can print them an work with them one by one but the problem is that I want to add all locations ligne by ligne in waypoints in one function like in the exemple bellow :

```
 for (i in response.data) {
    if (response.data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      console.log( response.data[i].latitude  +' , '+  response.data[i].longitude );
    }
  }


  L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
      L.latLng(33.86477205,-5.57643056),
      L.latLng(33.86494131,-5.57304561),
      L.latLng(33.86425534,-5.57063162),
    ],
    show: false
  }).addTo(map);
```

I want to add all latitudes and longitudes printed by FOR but in one step not one by one , because I think there is no other way to work with this Leaflet method.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a simple case of [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) manipulation in Javascript. Given an array with arbitrary data, you want a second array with instances of `L.LatLng`.

A straightforward approach is to [`map()` the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), e.g.:

```
  // For every data point in response.data, create a LatLng
  var waypoints = response.data.map(function(dataPoint){
    // console.log(dataPoint); // It might be useful to inspect these values
    return L.latLng(dataPoint.latitude, dataPoint.longitude);
  });

  // console.log(waypoints);  // Uncommenting this should display an Array of LatLngs

  L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: waypoints,
    show: false
  }).addTo(map);
```